# DriverManager can't open SQL connector jar

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception, connector-j

It's really weird, but please hear out the story.

We both know the behavior of DriverManager during connector registering. I swear it was worked as expected, then suddenly it started keep throwing SQLException: no suitable driver found. To fix it, I have to break the jar file and expose the content folders directly under the classpath with my bare hand.

I then concluded that something stopped my DriverManager from being able to open the jar file automatically. It looks like a weird access permission problem. My system is windows 8.1 and I run java under administrator:cmd.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bobbooks";

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "password");

    }
}
```

I have few classpath folders, only one of them contains the jar file.

OK, here is the code below, just a simple test class

I really want to fix this problem nicely, without breaking the jar file. Somebody help pls

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if I understood what I was learning, but here I got the solution:

Simply edit the environment variable, to add the jar file as a CLASSPATH, like this:

(CLASSPATH:)

D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar;

then it works just fine.

Comment: Note that this works in simple cases, but most ways of executing Java programs will ignore the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.